# multi dimensional array in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

Please explain the output of first and last `printf` statements. I think they should give the same output.

```
int main()
{
   char arr[5][7][6];
   char (*p)[5][7][6] = &arr;

   printf("%d\n", (&arr + 1) - &arr);
   printf("%d\n", (char *)(&arr + 1) - (char *)&arr);
   printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(arr + 1) - (unsigned)arr);
   printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(p + 1) - (unsigned)p);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
210
42
210
```

Comment: The interesting one is the third value...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I thought nobody was going to say anything about it :-))

Answer (score 4):

Lets see the memory layout first:

`char arr[5][7][6];` here `arr` is a array of arrays of arrays.

It will be laid out into memory like following:

```
+--------------+ 
|              | arr[0]
+--------------+
|              | arr[1]
+--------------+
|              | arr[2]
+--------------+
|              | arr[3]
+--------------+

etc.
```

Now `arr[i]` is a array of arrays of `char`.

So `a[i]` will be like

```
+--------------+  a[i][0]
|              |
+--------------+
|              |  a[i][1]
+--------------+
|              |  a[i][2]
+--------------+
|              |  a[i][3]
+--------------+

etc
```

Now `arr[i][j]` is a array of `chars`.

So

```
+--------------+ 
|              | arr[i][j][0]
+--------------+
|              | arr[i][j][1]
+--------------+ 
|              | arr[i][j][2]
+--------------+

etc.
```

Compiler will make an entry in its symbol table with name `arr` and with the address of its first block and also keep track of the total size (5*6*7 = 210 bytes).

Now the expression

```
printf("%d\n", (&arr + 1) - &arr);
```

Its a pointer arithmetic. So it will bound to type of every symbols.

Lets see this in action.

```
(gdb) p &arr
$1 = (char (*)[5][7][6]) 0x7fffffffe160
```

You see the type of `arr` is pointer `char (*)[5][6][7]`

In other words its pointer to a array of arrays of arrays. Pointer arithmetic actually do relates to the type the pointer is pointed to. So its important what is the size of the type.

```
(gdb) p sizeof(char [5][7][6])
$2 = 210
```

So any pointer to the type `char [5][6][7]` will be incremented or decremented like follows:

`&arr+1 => 0x7fffffffe160 +0xd2 => 0x7fffffffe232`

and `(&arr + 1) - &arr => 0x7fffffffe232 - 0x7fffffffe160=> 0xd2`

Now it returns actually **0xd2**. but for pointer arithmetic it means `1*sizeof(char [5][7][6]) => 1`

Pointer arithmetic returns the `number of sizeof(type)` instead of actual byte offset.

You are getting correct result for

```
printf("%d\n", (char *)(&arr + 1) - (char *)&arr);
```

Because of the casting you are making it a char pointer. So the pointer arithmetic will use unit `sizeof(char)` which  is of 1 byte size. And hence the output will be 210.

`printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(arr + 1) - (unsigned)arr);`

Here `arr` in a expression will decay to type `char (*)[7][6]` So its a pointer to a two dimensional array. The type its pointing to has a size 6*7 = 42. Thats what you are getting as result.

printf("%d\n", (unsigned)(p + 1) - (unsigned)p);

Here, `p+1 - p` will result in pointer arithmetic `1 * sizeof(char(*)[5][6][7])`. So in pointer arithmetic, it should return 1. But because of your casting the results of to unsigned , it will abandon pointer arithmetic and use integer arithmetic. Because of using integer arithmetic, it will treat the pointer values of large numbers, so you will get the actual byte offset.

Answer (score 2):

They would print the same result if they were treated as pointers, but in the last `printf` you're forcing them to be treated as unsigned integers by casting. Thus, `p + 1` and `p` are subtracted following integer arithmetic rules, as opposed to pointer arithmetic rules.

#### EDIT

To make things a little clearer:

- When you subtract 2 pointers the result is the number of elements
  between them. In your case there's 1 element between them
- When you cast the pointers to `unsigned` you're telling the compiler
  "these are just plain numbers, nothing to see here". So the compiler treats
  the addresses as numbers and just subtracts them.

Answer (score 0):

The first takes the address of `arr` and add one, then subtracts the address, the result is clearly 1.

The last one though, `p` is a pointer to `char [5][7][7]`, and using `(*p)[x][y][z]` can be though of as `p[0][x][y][z]`. So `(p + 1)` could be thought of as `p[1]`, which is 210 (`5 * 7 * 6`) bytes away from `p`.

If you did `(((unsigned) p) + 1) - ((unsigned) p)` then that would be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

the distance between the adresses is 1 element or 210 bytes

The first print prints the number of elements
The last - the number of bytes